# Python at the command line with relative paths

Tags: python

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
eclipse-workspace/simple_python
```

I can successfully call a python file at the command line from within the 'simple_python' folder as follows:

```
%python3.8 external.py
```

Now I wish to call the same file from a relative path, that is the folder above 'simple_python' as follows:

```
%python3.8 external.py /simple_python
```

However, I get an error message saying 'can't open file 'external.py''

What is the correct format for relative path addressing thanks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enter the it in the format `<directoryname>/<filename.py>`

So if you are in `eclipse-workspace` directory then you need to run it as :

```
%python3.8 simple_python/external.py
```